# plot not rendered under D3.js version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to port a d3 chart (which I found online) to v4 but for some reason only the axes are shown and nothing else. The code runs without any errors in the console of Chrome's developer tools and I have hit the wall as I am not an advanced d3 user. Any ideas are highly appreciated.
Here are two jsfiddles, in v3 and v4

https://jsfiddle.net/54mp286c/31/

https://jsfiddle.net/54mp286c/36/

and this is the d3 v4 code

```
var data = [{
  "Cell_Num": 0,
  "y": 3,
  "x": 2
}, {
  "Cell_Num": 1,
  "y": 3,
  "x": 6
}, {
  "Cell_Num": 2,
  "y": 7,
  "x": 1
}, {
  "Cell_Num": 3,
  "y": 5,
  "x": 5
}]

var margin = {
    top: 10,
    left: 50,
    bottom: 30,
    right: 10
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var scale = {
  x: d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).nice(),
  y: d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).nice()
};

var access = {
  x: function(d) {
    return d.x;
  },
  y: function(d) {
    return d.y;
  }
};

var value = {
  x: function(d) {
    return scale.x(access.x(d));
  },
  y: function(d) {
    return scale.y(access.y(d));
  }
};

var axis = {
  x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x),
  y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y)
};

var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");

svg.call(renderPlot, data);

function renderPlot(selection, data) {
  updateScales(data);

  selection.select(".x.axis").call(axis.x)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

  selection.select(".y.axis").call(axis.y);

  selection
    .call(renderVoronoi, data)
    .call(renderPoints, data);
}

function renderVoronoi(selection, data) {
  var voronoi = d3.voronoi()
    .x(value.x)
    .y(value.y)
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ]);

  var polygons = selection.selectAll(".voronoi")
    .data(voronoi(data));

  polygons.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "voronoi")
    .on("mouseenter", function(d, i) {
      var datum = selection.selectAll(".point").data()[i];
      selection.call(renderCrosshair, datum);
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function(d, i) {
      selection.selectAll(".crosshair").remove();
    });

  polygons
    .attr("d", d3.line());

  polygons.exit()
    .remove();
}

function renderCrosshair(selection, datum) {
  var lineData = [
    // vertical line
    [
      [value.x(datum), height],
      [value.x(datum), 0]
    ],
    // horizontal line
    [
      [0, value.y(datum)],
      [width, value.y(datum)]
    ]
  ];

  var crosshairs = selection.selectAll(".crosshair.line").data(lineData);

  crosshairs.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "crosshair line");

  crosshairs
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line());

  crosshairs.exit()
    .remove();

  var labelData = [{
      x: -6,
      y: value.y(datum) + 4,
      text: Math.round(access.y(datum)),
      orient: "left"
    },
    {
      x: value.x(datum),
      y: height + 16,
      text: Math.round(access.x(datum)),
      orient: "bottom"
    }
  ];

  var labels = selection.selectAll(".crosshair.label").data(labelData);

  labels.enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "crosshair label");

  labels
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.orient === "left" ? "end" : "middle";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.text;
    });

  labels.exit().remove();
}

function renderPoints(selection, data) {
  var points = selection.selectAll(".point").data(data);

  points.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("cx", value.x)
    .attr("cy", value.y)
    .attr("r", 0)
    .style("opacity", 0);

  points
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", value.x)
    .attr("cy", value.y)
    .attr("r", 2)
    .style("opacity", 1);

  points.exit()
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("r", 0)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();
}

function updateScales(data) {
  var extent = {
    x: d3.extent(data, access.x),
    y: d3.extent(data, access.y)
  };

  scale.x.domain([extent.x[0] - 0.5, extent.x[1] + 0.5]);
  scale.y.domain([extent.y[0] - 0.5, extent.y[1] + 0.5]);
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The issue was with your update pattern in V4. I've corrected the points update here: https://jsfiddle.net/wk2ygaL8/

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan! Really nice, any ideas how to make the crosshair show up as well please?

Comment: You're really far off from getting the lines. You don't actually call the crosshair function (that I can see). The data for the crosshair function isn't translating into the `linedata` object. You haven't defined a line function... it's a bit much.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for helping out anyway.